# Ploting scales on both sides of the y axis in a boxplot

Tags: r

I am making a boxplot using the following code. However, I want to add the scales to both sides of the y axis and not just the left side? How can I do this?

```
boxplot(data_aod[state=="UTTARANCHAL",c(7,9,11,13,15,17)], 
        main="Maxt and Mint observed in UTTARANCHAL")
```

Comment: please read the last paragraph of [this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), then go back to your previously asked questions

Answer (score 2):

have a look at `?axis`

```
axis(side = 4)
```

adds an axis on the right side of the boxplot. For example:

```
boxplot(rnorm(100))
axis(side = 4)
```

Comment: You may want to do something like `par(mar=c(5,4,4,3)+0.1)` beore the plot to leave room on the right for axis tick labels, etc.